# How to maintain lighting/shadows while making object transparent in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, shadows, lighting-effects, image-processing

[image]

Essentially I'm trying to make another background, beneath this image, become the colour of the object. The object/phone is red, the under-background is a linear gradient of colour and I'm trying to have that linear-gradient of colour come through instead of the red.

All the while maintaining the lighting/shadows of the object. None of the solutions I've attempted have seemed even close to correct. Could luminousity masks have something to do with a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible method

Layer 1: gradient

Layer 2: mask on white fill

Layer 3: desaturated original, set to multiply mode, layer opacity reduced to 69%

Layer 4: same as layer 3, but with inverted mask applied, set to hard light mode, opacity 100%

[image]

Please excuse the bad quality of the GIF, because GIFs don't do gradients very well.

Here's a sample showing the before and after, but with better quality

[image]

Comment: Could I ask a question or two tomorrow, if I have trouble implementing your solution? Also, thanks, this seems excellent.

Comment: @BillRobbins Sure you can ask for clarification if there's something you don't understand.

Comment: I should have mentioned then, that the background I'm relying on is a CSS linear gradient with the GIMP image sitting on top of it. Also, I'm a complete novice at GIMP, some basic points elude me

Comment: @BillRobbins Then you'll probably need to come up with something that doesn't use layer blending modes.  For example, here I created separate highlights and shadow layers using GIMP's  Colour to Alpha filter https://imgur.com/mmztsUt - obviously, it's not going to look as good as using layer blending modes inside GIMP. Instead you'd just have semi transparent pixels laying on top of a background, with no computation. Maybe it could be tweaked a bit using levels.

Comment: Alright then, it would function much like a children's book with plastic overlays that build up an image.

Comment: @BillRobbins -yes exactly

Comment: One last thing, only asking as I'm unfamilar with GIMP. Could you go through the layer 1-4 method in more detail?  I'm definitely missing mini-steps as my best results are no where near yours.

"let no good turn go unpunished"

Comment: @BillRobbins - it's a bit hard to do that here, as GDSE isn't really set up for full scale tutorials, and it's a bit frowned on here.  What I would do is search for basic beginner tutorials on GIMP - on the subject of creating layers and layer masks, and how to use the Colour to Alpha filter. There are lots on youtube. It's hard to run before you have learnt how to walk.

Comment: @BillRobbins remember if you get stuck on anything in particular, you can always ask a new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120133/discussion-between-bill-robbins-and-billy-kerr).